# Шестнадцатеричная система счисления

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как перевести число из шестнадцатеричной системы счисления, записанное в `char`, в `int`. Т.е например:

```
char c = 'A'; int code = 10; // код А
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string hexValue = new String(c);
```

потом конвертируешь так

```
int decValue = int.Parse(hexValue, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

или

```
int decValue = Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16);
```

Comment: спасибо! Странно, но сначала у меня ToInt32 не работал:3, видимо накосячил)